# React native animation through error when using useNativeDriver: true why?

Tags: react-native

Trying to generate a wave animation using Animated library of react native. It is working when I set useNativeDriver to false but it has lag. But when I set it to true it is giving error

"Attempt to run JS driven animation on animated node that has been moved to "native" earlier by starting an animation with 'useNativeDriver: true'

How I can fix this so my animation works smooth?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Animated, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default WaveAnimation = React.memo(() => {

  const [animatedValue, setAnimatedValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
  const [opacityA, setOpacityA] = useState(new Animated.Value(0.3))
  const [animatedValue1, setAnimatedValue1] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
  const [opacityB, setOpacityB] = useState(new Animated.Value(0.3))
  const [animatedValue2, setAnimatedValue2] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
  const [opacityC, setOpacityC] = useState(new Animated.Value(0.3))
  const [animatedValue3, setAnimatedValue3] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))
  const [opacityD, setOpacityD] = useState(new Animated.Value(0.3))

  const AnimationTime = 4000;

  const animateWave = () => {
    Animated.stagger(1000, [
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(animatedValue1, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: AnimationTime,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }),
          Animated.timing(opacityB, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: AnimationTime,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }),
        ])
      ),
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: AnimationTime,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }),
          Animated.timing(opacityA, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: AnimationTime,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }),
        ])
      ),
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(animatedValue2, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: AnimationTime,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }),
          Animated.timing(opacityC, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: AnimationTime,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }),
        ])
      ),
      Animated.loop(
        Animated.parallel([
          Animated.timing(animatedValue3, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: AnimationTime,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }),
          Animated.timing(opacityD, {
            toValue: 0,
            duration: AnimationTime,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }),
        ])
      ),
    ]).start()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    animateWave()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.waveStyle, {
            opacity: opacityA,
            transform: [
              { scale: animatedValue },
            ]
          }]}
        />
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.waveStyle, {
            opacity: opacityB,
            transform: [
              { scale: animatedValue1 },
            ]
          }]}
        />
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.waveStyle, {
            opacity: opacityC,
            transform: [
              { scale: animatedValue2 },
            ]
          }]}
        />
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.waveStyle, {
            opacity: opacityD,
            transform: [
              { scale: animatedValue3 },
            ]
          }]}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  )
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  waveStyle: { borderRadius: 200, width: 400, height: 400, backgroundColor: '#000', position: 'absolute', zIndex: 9999999, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't use *state* with Animated API. Just use values as such and they won't cause unnecessary cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Only some values are supported in native like transform, opacity, and some others. For the values not supported, animations are driven by JS bridge which can block your JS thread. So maybe you're running too much js animations at same time, and/or you're running other blocking code at same time. Just try to not overload animations and not sending requests or something at same time.

Like Samuli Hakoniemi said, you shouldn't use states to store your animated values, a simple var or const is enough, that prevent unnecessary render.

Comment: it was working in a tutorial video but not for me.

Comment: What was working ? That was smoother ? Do you have additionnal code compared to the tutorial ? Are you doing requests ? Do you set your animated values as normal variables like in Samuli Hakoniemi comment ? Need more infos

Comment: from my investigation I found that, Animated.loop and useNativeDriver only work on latest version of React-native. Not on v0.62. I guess i've got my answers, anyway thanks for your reply